# If $f(2n)=\frac1{f(n)+1}$ and $f(2n+1)=f(n)+1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, then find $n$ such that $f(n)=14/5$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recurrence-relations, functional-equations, rational-numbers

> The set $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of nonnegative integers.  Let $ f : \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{Q}$ be defined such that
>
> 1.) $f(2n) = \dfrac{1}{f(n)+1}$ for all integers $n>0$, and
>
> 2.) $f(2n + 1 ) = f(n)+1$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$.
>
> If $f(0)=0$, then determine the value of $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=\dfrac{14}{5}$.

Comment: $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$?

Comment: The tag `[injective-module]` has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: You asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765665/prove-that-a-function-f-bbbn-rightarrow-bbbq-is-injective) before, which was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273246/injectivity-and-surjectivity-of-a-recursive-function).  In the latter, it looks like there are constructive proofs of surjectivity...have you tried to apply these?

Comment: As linked by lulu there's a proof that $f(n)$ is bijective. Then realise that $\frac{14}{5}=1+1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{4}}$ and construct $n$ step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(n)>0$ for $n>0$, $f(n)>1$ for odd $n$ and $f(n)<1$ for even $n$, you can see that if $f(n)=\frac{14}{5}$, $n$ must be odd, that is $n = 2n_1+1$, where $f(n_1) = \frac 95$. Proceeding in this manner, you get
$$
n_1 = 2n_2+1, n_2 = 2n_3, n_3 = 2n_4, n_4=2n_5+1, n_5=2n_6+1, n_6 = 2n_7+1, n_7=0
$$

going back, the answer is $n=115$.

Answer (score 0):

One readily sees that $f(n)>0$ for all $n>0$.
It follows that $f(n)>1$ only if $n$ is even and $0<f(n)<1$ only if $n$ is odd.
From this, $f(n_1)=\frac{14}5$ implies $n_1=2n_2$ with $f(n_2)=\frac95$.
Then $n_2=2n_3$ with $f(n_3)=\frac45$. Then $n_3=2n_4+1$ with $f(n_4)=\frac14$. Then ... proceed until you hit $1$ (and then $0$); this *will* happen because the sum of numerator and denominator is decreasing.

Comment: isnt $f(2n) = \frac{1}{f(n)+1} = 14/5 $ ?